Detect terminal detachment in Docker container bash?
If someone runs docker run --rm -it debian:bookworm /bin/bash -l, is there some way from within the bash shell I can determine that the user has detached the terminal?
I have tried testing stdin and stdout but they both appear open and normal. I tried trapping SIGPIPE and writing to stdout but that did not work either. I am thinking that Docker intentionally (because of the -i) prevents the shell from knowing the terminal has been detached. Is there any way to detect it?
Note that changing the Docker command line is not an option, as I am not the one launching the image. I am trying to help out users who launch my (Debian-based) image using -it when they should not be doing that. In my particular situation, despite the -it, I want the container to quit when the terminal is detached.

As you can verify from docker run --help, the option -i, --interactive                      keeps STDIN open even if not attached.
Other than that, why are you interested in detecting that condition?
whatever you are running should run the same either attached or detacched.
